# cognitoUser.refreshSession keeps refreshing user login

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

Im trying to refresh the jwt token with cognitoUser.refreshSession, everytime I log in it simply refreshes the login page and asks me to sign in again

I have written up some code from various examples I have found but still struggle to get it going. If anyone has any suggestions I would welcome them:

Code as follows:

```js
import axios from 'axios';
import { Auth } from 'aws-amplify';

const httpClient = axios.create(
  { baseURL: process.env.VUE_APP_API_BASE_URL }
);

const refreshToken = async function() {
    try {
        const cognitoUser = await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser();
        const currentSession = await Auth.currentSession();
        cognitoUser.refreshSession(currentSession.refreshToken, (err, session) => {
            console.log('session', err, session);
            return Auth.user.signInUserSession.idToken.jwtToken
        });
    } catch (e) {
        console.log('Unable to refresh Token', e);
    }
}

httpClient.interceptors.request.use(
  config => {
    const idToken = refreshToken()
    config.headers.Authorization = idToken;
    return config
  }, error => Promise.reject(error))


export default httpClient;
```

Comment: given that this is from amplify can you enable logging on amplify and see whats events are occurring the link for how to enable amplify loggin is here https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/utilities/logger/q/platform/js/

Comment: Ill ask the server ops to pop it in and see whats going on